# CUDA Can't allocate more than 6.8Gb memory on a 8Gb card

Tags: cuda

I have a GTX1070 card with 8GB onboard memory,however can't get past ~6.8Gb allocation point with cudaMalloc. The GPU is headless,so,it's not used for OS rendering GUI needs. I would have understood if there had been something like 100-200Mb out of 8GB memory unreachable for some internal reasons,but 1.2GB?! The OS is Win10 64. Does anyone know what it might be?

Comment: You would need to provide more information before your could reasonably get an answer. Have you checked how much *actual* free memory the runtime reports is available on the device before starting allocation? Are you allocating a single large allocation, or many small ones? Are you doing these allocations in contexts with kernels which have large local memory requirements? There are potenitally a lot of reasons why this might happen, I can't say which without a lot more information about what it is you are actually trying to do.

Comment: The fact that your GTX1070 GPU is "headless" is mostly irrelevant in terms of how windows interacts with it at the driver level.  A display driver stack is still being built on that GPU, and things like WDDM TDR still apply. As @talonmies indicated, more information would be needed, such as the output from `cudaMemGetInfo` at various points in  the program for which the allocation is failing, as well as a short test program itself.  As suggested in the answer, many non-obvious things can contribute to memory usage on the GPU.

Answer (score 1):

(Potentially) having a lot of threads running in parallel requires a lot of memory that is kept available in various pools. You can use the [cudaDeviceSetLimit()](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1g05956f16eaa47ef3a4efee84563ccb7d) call to configure a number of those pools:

- The device stack.
- The FIFO buffer that device side `printf()` uses to buffer it's arguments until the host can output them.
- The buffer that device side `malloc()` calls allocate from.
- Memory used to implement device side calls to `cudaDeviceSynchronize()`.
- The queue for device side kernel launches.

Apart from the stack all of these memory pools are for supporting optional functionality. If you don't make use of those optional functions, or can limit their use, you can save memory by configuring the corresponding limit before the first kernel launch.